# Interpreting a list of lambdas

Tags: python, lambda, callable

I have a list which contains some lambda elements too:

```
l=['A',lambda x:x*2,lambda x:x*3]
```

How do I append this list to another after executing the lambda(something like below - obviously this one doesnt work):

```
m=list(k=k(3) if isinstance(k,types.FunctionType) else k for k in l)
```

The out expected is :

```
m=['A',6,9]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`callable`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#callable).

```
>>> l = ['A', lambda x:x*2, lambda x:x*3]
>>> m = [k(3) if callable(k) else k for k in l]
>>> m
['A', 6, 9]
```

Comment: one should remember that callable of class is true too ```isinstance(a, type) and callable(a) == True```

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure you want to append this list to another, or make a new list?
Just in case you happen to use a version of python where callable is deprecated:

```
for element in l:
    m.append(element(3) if hasattr(element, '__call__') else element)
```

Comment: use ```callable``` instead of ```hasattr(element, '__call__')```

Comment: @oleg the main issue is this use of ternary `if` when the result is not used

Comment: If you are using Python3.0 or 3.1 you should use `isinstance(element, collections.Callable)` instead of `callable()`. In 3.2+ `callable()` was resurrected.

Comment: @jamylak do you mean the equivalent line should be something like: `m.append(element(3) if hasattr(element, '__call__') else element)` ? (Ignoring callable issue) Thanks

Comment: @andy That's nicer, it actually uses ternary `if` like it's supposed to.